# Is there any way to make 300k by 300k matrix in r?

Tags: r

I want to make large matrix like 300k by 300k matrix using R.

Many people recommended "bigmemory" package and i tried to make matrix using it.
when I make small matrix, it works but when I tried with large matrix, it gave me an error message.

[image]

How could i solve this problem?
Or do you know the way to create large matrix (in my case, 300k by 300k) in r?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Even if you manage to create it somehow, you won't be able to do anything with it.

Comment: Agree with Roland.  Better to state your analytical objective that ostensibly requires a matrix of that size.  Perhaps a work-around could be suggested for you instead.

Comment: this is "only" 353G, so I can believe it's *possible* (don't know why you're getting that error) - but I agree that some context would help you get an answer. (Do you have considerably more than 353G of disk space ... ?)

Comment: I want to make adjacency matrix for analyzing methylation data,so I tried to make room first. I need a matrix that inform which CpG site are connected. @Roland

Comment: My goal is above. Thanks for you advice! @SteveM

Comment: In what format are the data you're going to use to construct the adjacency matrix?  How sparse do you expect the adjacency matrix to be?

Comment: Any format that can calculate inner product would be ok. It will sparse quite a lot. @BenBolker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since R works on CPUs only, I don't think modern day personal computers can handle that amount of information. I happened to work with relatively large data tables (8 million rows * ~500 variables) and my PC crashed few times.

However, if you work with **sparse objects** (not sure it's what you need), you might find tricks to reduce the memory size of the matrix. You can find something on sparse matrices in R [on this blog](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2011/10/31/using-sparse-matrices-in-r/).

Comment: Thanks. your comment helps me a lot. I'll try!